# Passing an array to Get-Job

Tags: arrays, powershell, powercli

I am having trouble getting an array passed to a scriptblock in Start-Job.  Can you tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
$bounceBlock = {
param(
[string[]]$list,
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$cred
)
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core | Out-Null
Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -DefaultVIServerMode Multiple -Scope User -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
Connect-VIServer -Server servername -Credential $cred -AllLinked
Get-VM -Name $list
}


if ($targets) {
$activeTargets = $targets | Get-Random -Count $prodTargets.Count
$counter = [pscustomobject] @{Value = 0}
$groupSize = 50
$groups = $activeTargets | Group-Object -Property {[math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $groupSize)}
$connection = Connect-VIServer -Server servername -Credential $cred -AllLinked
if ($connection -match "servername") {
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        while ((Get-Job -State Running).Count -ge 5) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $bounceBlock -ArgumentList (,$group.Group.ServerName),$cred
        }
    Disconnect-VIServer * -Force -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

I basically split an array into chunks of 50 (working) then try to run them as jobs.  The error I get looks like it's trying to run Get-VM for a single server, named all 50 values appended together.

Comment: `-ArgumentList $group.Group.ServerName, $cred` should suffice. What PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: Powershell 4.  If I try to pass it like that, the job hangs forever (or at least longer than 20 minutes).

Comment: One Additional note, if I just try to run the command with a regular array outside of the loop, the job still hangs.  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $bounceBlock -ArgumentList $stuff,$cred

Comment: Did @($group.Group.ServerName) not work for you? The unary operator probably would have a one element array that contained an array.

Comment: Well, I created an array of servers and tried passing it manually outside of the script (just sent it to the 'bounceblock' directly) and that didn't work either.  I think the issue is in the action itself.

Comment: What's the actual error you get?

Comment: Beyond the answer I gave; I will also share find that naming the jobs is a good practice as well so you can locate them, stop them and kill them later. In your scenario, I use a naming convention of servername+action. It helps if others are administering jobs and come across yours. Not that they should be deleting jobs they have no business with but a descriptive name will make them think twice if they easily can tell what the job is related to.

Comment: @briantist I am not sure.  The jobs start and never complete.  Perhaps this is also an issue where I am not knowledgeable enough about determining what the error actually is.

Comment: Have you tried running the bounceBlock as a loop rather than as a job? Just to see if it works?

Comment: I have.  It works just fine standalone.

Comment: From what I see we can't tell what `$targets` is. My question is what is the type of `$group.Group.ServerName` in the loop? `$group.Group.ServerName.GetType().Fullname`. Also seems redundant to run `Connect-VIServer` in the block every time. Wonder if multiple sessions are not allowed.

Comment: I thought of that too...  I tried running it with only enough servers for one session, and that still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted everyone to know in case they run into a similar problem, this is an issue with running Get-VM, and it exists whether running it in a job or workflow.  VMWare is aware of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly no expert with PS, but first to address how you're passing in the appended list of servers; I do something similar with Azure VMs using Get-AzureVM and I pass in my list of VM names in a System.Array to functions or cmdlets such as a variable such as $theVMs= "MyServer1","MyServer2","MyServer3" 
*and then I execute a foreach loop over ($vm in $theVMs)* and then perform the actions such as Get-VM sequentially. I do this sequentially since PS has some much lower limits, 5 per my experience, doing this via a parallel for loop.

A typical way I interact with the VMs remotely **and create a PS Job per each** is to use 
     $uri = Get-AzureWinRMUri -ServiceName $svc -Name $vmname

```
 Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri $uri -Credential $creds **-JobName 
 $jobname**    
 -ArgumentList $vmname -ScriptBlock {
 param([string]$thevm) ...
 }
```

This requires the InstallWinRMCertAzureVM.ps1 script which is discussed and available at [http://blogs.technet.com](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/09/07/weekend-scripter-remoting-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-and-powershell.aspx) . I use this for between 30 servers regularly.

Comment: This is not Azure, it's PowerCLI.  I don't think your solution would apply.